# How properly bind an array with ngModel from ngFor loop in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

Am using `ngModel` inside of an `ngFor` loop to get values from a single input box like so :

```
  <mat-card class="hours"  >
  <table id="customers">
      <thead >
          <th >Project</th>
          <th *ngFor="let day of weeks">{{day | titlecase}}</th> //weeks is one week dates
          <th>Total Hours</th>
          <th></th>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let employee of projectTasks; let i = index">
            <td>{{employee.Project}}</td>
            <td *ngFor="let day of weekdays"> //weekdays are monday to saturday
                <input type="number" [id]="day" [(ngModel)]="employee[day]" class="hours-input">
            </td>
            <td class="total-cell">{{getTotalHours(employee)}}</td>
            <td>
              <button mat-icon-button class="codered" (click)="deleteproject(employee, i)" >
                  <mat-icon >delete</mat-icon>
              </button>
          </td>

        </tr>

      </tbody>

  </table>
  <button mat-raised-button color="primary" class="submit" (click)="CreateTimeSheet()" >Submit</button>
```

[image: input box values has to push into array]
[image]

My typescript:

```
 addProject(): void {
    this.pProjectId++;
  this.projectTasks.push({

    projectId: this.projectData[0].projectdetails[0]._id,
    Project: this.selected,
    monday: 0,
    tuesday: 0,
    wednesday: 0,
    thursday: 0,
    friday: 0,
    saturday: 0,
    sunday: 0,
  });
  console.log(this.projectTasks, "entered data");     
  }
```

bind an array with ngModel in ng for loop please refer to the image i have attached can any one help me out how to do  any help appreciated.

Comment: Binding like this should work.  How is the Weekdays array defined?  What do you expect to happen?  what is happening?  Are you seeing any console errors?

Comment: Hi  weekdays array defined as -- weekdays: string[] = ["monday", "tuesday", "wednesday","thursday","friday","saturday","sunday"]; no console errors  @JeffryHouser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to use trackBy on ngFor as below and I have added the Plnkr example link.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <div>
    <div *ngFor="let item of toDos;let index = index;trackBy:trackByIndex;">
      <input [(ngModel)]="toDos[index]" type="number" placeholder="item">
    </div>
    Below Should be binded to above input box
    <div *ngFor="let item of toDos">
      <label>{{item}}</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  `,
  directives: [MdButton, MdInput]
})
export class AppComponent { 
  toDos: string[] =[1,2,3];
  constructor() {}
  ngOnInit() {}
  trackByIndex(index: number, obj: any): any {
    return index;
  }
}
```

[Example Plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/nqmCuKUdRhWwF2X3?preview)

Thanks

Comment: Hi it works for now  but my concern is , how to get total value  if i have numbers instead of string   toDos: [] =["1","2","3"];  @Jai Saravanan

Comment: Hi @aryana, I have updated the above answer & Plnkr example link to use the number instead of the string.

https://plnkr.co/edit/nqmCuKUdRhWwF2X3?preview

Kindly check it and if the answer is useful please upvote and support. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Jai Saravanan my concern is  how to display and get sum of total toDos = 5 and thanks for helping me  and sorry for late response